# Help identifying image of winged robed figure and young man

Tags: roman-empire, greek-mythology, sculpture

Our brand-new office building has this brass medallion in the floor in the lobby.  Is this a copy of some image from antiquity?  Or just something they made up?

[image: Floor Medallion]

Comment: I'm guessing that it's "in the style of..." since the ancients weren't so coy about genitalia.

Comment: The style to me looks a lot like the depression era WPA style (can't find an official name for this style).

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect to see it in an art deco style building in NYC or something, not in a blocky office building in suburbia.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the image is based on the myth of [Eos pursuing  Tithonos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tithonus):

[image]

Other images

- [Here](http://www.theoi.com/Titan/Eos.html)
- [and the image you have(apparently edited for today's sense of decency](http://www.theoi.com/Gallery/T19.6.html)

and appears on the cover of this book:

[Women in Greek Myth](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801886503) Paperback – January 16, 2007
by Mary R. Lefkowitz

Comment: You were 20 seconds faster, my daughter stopped me finishing my answer earlier :)

Comment: Yes, its funny how something can sit without an answer two will get posted at virtually the same time.